# What is a basic object detection/localization ML algorithm that can be used for my relatively simple image set?

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model, object-detection

I have a relatively simple object localization task. I have an image set that are either uniform or contain an 'object' consisting of a black circular shape at some position in the image. The labels include whether or not it contains the object, and the position of the object (center coordinates + length/width). YOLO feels like overkill and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get it to work, but I'm having a hard time finding a simpler model that would work.

Comment: What is learning bringing to this party?  Machine vision techniques would be quite simple compared to learning.

Answer (score 1):

So, the following techniques are used for object detection (other can YOLO, R-CNN and other Deep Learning Techniques):

#### Haar Cascade Classifier

This was the first facial detection algorithm to be successfully used and is popular until today. Proposed by Viola and Jones in their paper [Rapid Object Detection using a Boosted Cascade of Simple
Features (2001, CVPR)](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~efros/courses/LBMV07/Papers/viola-cvpr-01.pdf) this algorithm uses Haar-like features from integral images and a cascade of boosting classifiers to detect objects in images. Lienhart proposed in 2002 a improvement to this algorithm in his paper [Empirical Analysis of Detection Cascades of Boosted Classifiers for Rapid Object Detection](http://www.multimedia-computing.de/mediawiki//images/5/52/MRL-TR-May02-revised-Dec02.pdf)

It can be easily trained using OpenCV [Object Detection Module](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html) in Python, C and Java, also available in Matlab Computer Vision Tool Box as [vision.CascadeObjectDetector](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/train-a-cascade-object-detector.html) and probably many other platforms.

#### Max-Margin Object Detection

Proposed in the paper [Max-Margin Object Detection](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.00046.pdf) by Davis E. King, creator of [dlib](http://dlib.net/), where it has been implemented, this algorithm has implementations for face detection using HoG Features and CNNs features.

The abstract of the paper goes:

> Most object detection methods operate by applying a binary classifier
>   to sub-windows of an image, followed by a non-maximum suppression step
>   where detections on overlapping sub-windows are removed. Since the
>   number of possible sub-windows in even moderately sized image datasets
>   is extremely large, the classifier is typically learned from only a
>   subset of the windows. This avoids the computational difficulty of
>   dealing with the entire set of subwindows, however, as we will show in
>   this paper, it leads to sub-optimal detector performance.
>
> In particular, the main contribution of this paper is the introduction
>   of a new method, Max-Margin Object Detection (MMOD), for learning to
>   detect objects in images. This method does not perform any
>   sub-sampling, but instead optimizes over all sub-windows. MMOD can be
>   used to improve any object detection method which is linear in the
>   learned parameters, such as HOG or bag-of-visual-word models. Using
>   this approach we show substantial performance gains on three publicly
>   available datasets. Strikingly, we show that a single rigid HOG filter
>   can outperform a state-of-the-art deformable part model on the Face
>   Detection Data Set and Benchmark when the HOG filter is learned via
>   MMOD.

I think these are the two most relevant outside of Deep Learning, reading the related work fromt he 3 cited articles might give you some light on how to proceed.